# Can you use twinned spell on the same target?

Tags: dnd-5e, sorcerer, metamagic

So me and my DM have been arguing on how Twinned spell works.

**Twinned spell:**

> When you cast a spell that targets only one creature and  doesn't have
> a range of self, you can spend a number of  sorcery points equal to
> the spell's level to target **a second**  creature in range with the
> same spell (1 sorcery point if  the spell is a cantrip).

I argued that "**a second creature**" can be a the same target as it is not worded as "**another creature**"

For this example counter spell with twinned spell.

> A wizard casts fireball on me
>
> I use CounterSpell#1 with Twinned Spell
>
> Wizard casts CounterSpell on my CounterSpell#1 I use him as the same
>
> target for my twinned Spell CounterSpell#2

Result countered

***Is this possible?***

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First off, "a second creature" is here synonymous with "another creature." Your DM is right on this front. Jeremy Crawford has [clarified such a point before](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/829087884955095040):

> **Q:** Hey, can twinned spell, target the same person twice?
>
> **Jeremy:** If a rule, such as Twinned Spell, says you affect one creature and then a second creature, those are two different creatures.

Second, Twinned Spell does not work *at all* with Counterspell. This is because Counterspell is cast in reaction to another creature casting a spell, and because of the way turn order/initiative works in D&D, there is no valid target at the time you twin the spell. It could also be argued that Counterspell targets a spell instead of a creature, but I'm not sure on that one.

Comment: I might add to your first paragraph that the design team for 5e has stated that rules should be read in simple idiomatic English, to add support to your interpretation that "a second creature" is supposed to mean "another creature" (since nobody would use "a second creature" to refer possibly to the same creature in simple English). Otherwise, without support, it would be reasonable for the asker to argue with you on that point.

Comment: On the second point, Counterspell doesn't mentioning targeting, so I think your last sentence ("it could also be argued that Counterspell targets a spell instead of a creature, but I'm not sure on that one") is probably not something you can argue. But it doesn't involve targeting a single creature so it definitely can't be used for Twinned Spell.

Comment: The rules are silent on handling multiple reactions with the same trigger. If the DM rules they happen simultaneously, it's possible for twinned counterspell to come up if two creatures try to counterspell the same spell.

Comment: @Doval I think that's different from what's happening here. It sounds like you're talking about two creatures countering the same spell, whereas the OP was asking about countering a spell, twinning the counterspell, and using the twin to counter something else.

Comment: You're correct. But your answer says "Twinned Spell does not work *at all* with Counterspell" and it occurred to me that's not necessarily true. And now that I think about it, a similar situation can occur if two creatures take the Ready action to cast a spell when the same trigger occurs. Anyways, my point is you might want to relax the wording on that phrase.

Comment: I'm still not sure I see your logic. The two scenarios are so different as to be effectively opposite to each other. Would like to have a third party weigh in on this, but it's getting a bit too long for comments.

Comment: @Passage This could help clarify things. [Dragon Talk - 01/19/2017](http://dnd.wizards.com/podcast-hub). JC goes into detail on just this topic, more so than what can fit in Twitter.